# bootstrap 4 / Saas navbar collapses as screen narrows but hamburger menu won't then work?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, handlebars.js, navbar, ember-bootstrap

I have some HTML which defines a bootstrap 4 navbar and works fine.

[image]

As the width of the window is reduced the detail of the navbar disappears and a hamburger menu appears.

[image]

When you click on the hamburger you see a menu which contains entries which correspond to those previously seen on the navbar.

[image]

The HTML looks like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's all fine but what I actually want is to use that markup in a handlebar template the styling of which goes through Saas . The entire template looks like this

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

When the template is rendered (with a full size window) the navbar is shown as you would expect. Simililary when the size of the window is reduced the navbar is shown with a hamburger menu as you would expect however when the hamburger is selected nothing happens .

Would be interested to hear of any idiosyncrasies between vanilla bootstrap and sass boostrap which might explain this ?

All of the examples are on a recent Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap adds the "show" class on clicking the hamburger. So to close the menu after clicking on an anchor tag all you have to do is this:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2kc1etv6/2/

Placement in your code w/ some other small tweaks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--Custom CSS-->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
     <!--navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#disabled">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!--smooth scroll-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scroll/16.1.3/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $( '#navbarText a' ).on('click', function(){
            $('#navbarText').removeClass('show');
        });
    </script>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo quas distinctio voluptates autem earum quos delectus natus aliquam vero ullam. Maiores cupiditate soluta veritatis voluptatibus ratione fuga nulla nisi mollitia. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quod qui perspiciatis provident modi ratione vitae quidem voluptate recusandae repudiandae quisquam eaque nesciunt nulla dolorem molestias ipsa, cupiditate harum a. </h1>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem aliquam ex inventore exercitationem dicta deleniti fugiat, molestiae eum accusantium. Minus eveniet eaque aut quibusdam delectus omnis doloremque necessitatibus quas laudantium?</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jason - I do appreciate your response but I'm afraid I didn't make myself clear. The menu works as I would expect it to for the first sample of markup (the one that you've provided a revised version of), it's the second sample of markup which, although it changes mode when the screen becomes narrow, doesn't shown the navbar contents when the hamburger menu is selected. I'd be interested to hear any other ideas you had and thanks for your response.